# Simple math game problems (beginner stuff)

Tags: javascript, html, math, project

I have a school project where we are making a small JavaScript game without a UI; this means we can only use prompt, alert or other popup scripts.

The game should work, at least it did before i broke it apart with the module. It's a simple math game where user gets random +, questions and has to answer them correctly

#### The problem(s)

I don't seem to be able to get any prompts to the user. I'm also having trouble debugging this in chrome dev tools, can you see anything that seems wrong right away? Thankful for any help at all :)

Heres the JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vuTGa/1/

This is our code, I only posted the vital parts - I left out the index.html and Mathgame.js because they seem to work perfect and also they do not contain a lot of code.

### MathGame.logic.js

```
mathGame.logic = (function() {
    "use strict";
    var createQuestion, getQuestion;
    createQuestion = function() {
        var tal1, tal2;
        tal1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
        tal2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
        return {
            tal1: tal1,
            tal2: tal2,
            result: function() {
                return tal1 + tal2;
            }
        };
    };
    getQuestion = function() {
        return createQuestion();
    };
    return {
        getQuestion: getQuestion
    };
}());
```

### MathGame.play.js

```
mathGame.play = function() {
    "use strict";
    var question, guess, answer, correct, questionGuess;
    // Starts game for user
    mathGame.ui.startCountDown();
    // Starts the timer in .logic
    // mathGame.logic.startCountDown();
    // Get random math
    question = mathGame.logic.getQuestion();
    // Send random math to User
    questionGuess = mathGame.ui.askMathQuestion(question.tal1, question.tal2);
    // The users guess
    guess = mathGame.ui.returnMathGuess;
    // See if the question is the same as the guess
    correct = (question() === guess);
    // Show the user how it went
    mathGame.ui.showResult(correct, guess, question);



    ##Mathgame.ui.js##
    mathGame.ui = {

        startCountDown: function() {
            "use strict";
            // Visa ready set go
            alert("READY");
            alert("SET");
            alert("GO");
        },
        askMathQuestion: function() {
            "use strict";
            prompt("askMathQuestion");
            //shows a math question to user
            // return Number(prompt(value1 + symbol +  value2));
            // e.g. value1 = 12
            //      value2 = 13
            //        symbol = "+"
            // 12 + 13  
            // return user guess
        },
        returnMathGuess: function() {
            "use strict";
        },
        showResult: function() {
            "use strict";
        }
    };
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Maybe you could put this on JSfiddle, so we can see what works and what doesn't?

Comment: oh sorry, adding it to the post right away

Comment: how to put multiple JS files in JSfiddle?

Comment: Click the Add Resources tab and insert the JavaScript file URL into the text box. I believe it has to be an online URL.

Comment: ok, any suggestion where to upload my files to get online url then ? :)

Comment: @nalyd, or just concatenate your scripts in the `JavaScript` pane.

Comment: as i said, im very thankful for any advice at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, so far I've only been able to pinpoint minor problems in your code. Since you're using strict mode, the window object's properties are not accessible globally. So you'll need to use `window.alert` or set a variable:

```
var alert = this.alert; // "this" being the global, window object
```

The first thing I noticed is that you didn't have a closing bracket to your `math.play` function declaration. I fixed that. But what the real problem you were having was that you were referencing properties of `mathGame` before they were created. For example, in the definition of `mathGame.play()`, you ran the function `mathGame.ui.startCountDown();` but `mathGame.ui` was defined in the function below the call. So I took it out the function so that it could have access to it. That was the general problem with your script.

There was also a part where you called an object as if it were a function:

```
correct = (question() === guess);
```

`question` was already defined as the return value of the function `mathGame.logic.getQuestion();` which was a string. I think you were confusing it with this:

```
question = mathGame.logic.getQuestion;

correct = (question() === guess); // now this works
```

I also fixed up some things I found superfluous. If you want the entire script to be in strict mode, then create a closure over it in strict mode:

```
(function() {
    "using strict";
    // everything below is in strict mode
})();
```

Here is the entire code:

```
(function() {
    "using strict";
    var mathGame = {},
        alert = this.alert,
        prompt = this.prompt;

    mathGame.play = function() {
        var question, guess, answer, correct, questionGuess;
        // Starts game for user
        mathGame.ui.startCountDown();
        // Starts the timer in .logic
        // mathGame.logic.startCountDown();
        // Get random math
        mathGame.logic = (function() {
            var createQuestion, getQuestion;
            createQuestion = function() {
                var tal1, tal2;
                tal1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
                tal2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
                return {
                    tal1: tal1,
                    tal2: tal2,
                    result: function() {
                        return tal1 + tal2;
                    }
                };
            };
            getQuestion = function() {
                return createQuestion();
            };
            return {
                getQuestion: getQuestion
            };
        }());

        question = mathGame.logic.getQuestion();
        // Send random math to User
        questionGuess = mathGame.ui.askMathQuestion(question.tal1, question.tal2);
        // The users guess
        guess = mathGame.ui.returnMathGuess;
        // See if the question is the same as the guess
        correct = (question === guess);
        // Show the user how it went
        mathGame.ui.showResult(correct, guess, question);
    };

    mathGame.ui = {

        startCountDown: function() {
            // Visa ready set go
            alert("READY");
            alert("SET");
            alert("GO");
        },
        askMathQuestion: function() {
            prompt("askMathQuestion");
            //shows a math question to user
            // return Number(prompt(value1 + symbol +  value2));
            // e.g. value1 = 12
            //      value2 = 13
            //        symbol = "+"
            // 12 + 13  
            // return user guess
        },
        returnMathGuess: function() {},
        showResult: function() {}

    };
    mathGame.play();
}).call(this); // global object
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gBW27/)

Note that in the HTML section of the code, I took out some script files because they were non-existent in website. If you need them again, here they are:

```
<script src="mathGame.js"></script>
<script src="mathGame.logic.js"></script>
<script src="mathGame.ui.js"></script>
<script src="mathGame.play.js"></script>
```

Comment: wonderful! going to check my code for thease errors, as i said i have my JS divided up into those 4 files, i will have a look and be back when im done reviewing :) thanks for the answer

Comment: sorry, im so new to this haha :D

Comment: this is great, but for some reason i can't split it up into the oroginal 4 files :P do you mind setting it so i can use it in my 4 files :)?

Comment: First file should have the definition of mathGame (`var mathGame = {}`). Then the `mathGame.logic` function definition in the next file. The next file should be the `mathGame.ui` definition. Then lastly the `mathGame.play` definition. -- http://jsfiddle.net/RL6hm/1/

Comment: so i should define
mathGame
mathgame.logic
mathgame.ui
and 
mathgame.play

in mathgame.js?

Comment: I was saying that they should all be separate script files defined one after the other but you can do that too.

Comment: yeah thats the way i have it now, still dosen't seem to work, is there any way to send my whole project to you so you can review it?

i mean all files separately

Comment: or you could post what to have in each separate file, would be so much easier for me to see where i did wrong ^^sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: I think it's the way you're naming the files! `mathGame.logic`/`mathgame.ui`/`mathgame.play` is an incorrect file name. The computer thinks `.logic`, `.ui` and `.play` are the file extensions. Rename them to something like `mathLogic`/`mathUI` and try again.

Comment: i dont think so because i can call functions from my html like this:

question = mathGame.logic.getQuestion();

the result is this:

question = mathGame.logic.getQuestion();
Object
result: function () {
tal1: 48
tal2: 53
__proto__: Object

Comment: @nalydbob I meant the name of the files. Like `<script src="mathGame.logic.js"></script>` You shouldn't have `mathGame.logic` but something like `mathGameLogic.js` as the name of the file on your computer. It's not about the JavaScript, it's about the *name* of the file containing it.

Comment: aha okay will try that too :)

Comment: Tried it, did not work :/ i think im still missing something in my code, could you just copy paste what you would have in the separate files and ill try that ? Thanks for your time btw<3

Comment: @nalydbob First I have: **mathgame.js**, then **mathlogic.js**, then **mathui.js**, then **mathplay.js**. In **game.html** I include these files in this order in the head element. In mathgame.js all I have written is `var mathGame = {};` . It code works for me just fine.

Comment: wow nice! mind uploading it somewhere ? i would be forever grateful if you did :)

Comment: This is the only way I know how: Open the HTML panel (to see the script elements and their code) and the Output panel to see the result (click "Run with JS" to see) -- http://jsbin.com/onisud/2/edit

Comment: Thanks soo much david!! now i only have to add the actuall math to the prompt and make the program understand when user is right or wrong ;)

<3<3<3

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tomasdev/vuTGa/2/ there were a bunch of syntax problems.

Comment: what exactly did you change tom :)?